# How can I return a Type object for a nullable type in Dart?

Tags: dart

I have a code generation library that needs to know the `Type` that is being generated.

Most of my code works fine because the type "wrapper" can trivially know the `Type` it's associated with. But in one case, I know that the type is `Object?` and I want to return that.

But I can't find a way to actually do it!

Here's code that works fine:

```dart
Type? typeFor(String name) {
  // simple examples
  if (name == 'String') return String;
  if (name == 'bool') return bool;
  return null;
}
```

Now, if I try to add `Object?`:

```dart
Type typeFor(String name) {
  // simple examples
  if (name == 'String') return String;
  if (name == 'bool') return bool;
  return Object?;
}
```

Dart thinks `Object?` is actually an incomplete ternary operator :(.

I tried `(Object?)` but that doesn't work either.

Is there a workaround for representing nullable types in Dart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a type alias:

```dart
typedef typeof<T> = T; // ignore: camel_case_types
```

(Or give it a camel-cased name, like `TypeOf`, if you want to follow the style guide.)

Then you can write *any* type as an expression as `typeof<TheType>`.

```dart
Type typeFor(String name) {
  // simple examples
  if (name == 'String') return String;
  if (name == 'bool') return bool;
  return typeof<Object?>;
}
```

Comment: I think that's better than a function, because it has on runtime cost, right?

Comment: Correct. Maybe the function can be just as efficient, if it's inlined and completely optimized away, but this way you should be sure. Also, using the type alias, the type object is a *constant*.

Answer (score 1):

Use a generic function where you can pass the type as a type parameter:

````dart
/// Identity function for a [Type].
///
/// This can be used in situations where a type literal is syntactically
/// invalid.
///
/// Example:
/// ```dart
/// x.runtimeType == int?; // Compile-time error due to invalid syntax.
/// x.runtimeType == identityType<int?>();
/// ```
Type identityType<T>() => T;

Type typeFor(String name) {
  // simple examples
  if (name == 'String') return String;
  if (name == 'bool') return bool;
  return identityType<Object?>();
}
````

(My [dartbag package](https://pub.dev/packages/dartbag/) also provides the above `identityType` function, although it's clearly quite trivial.)

Comment: Perfect, that works! I keep forgetting that any generic function in Dart actually has access to its type! Thanks.